# Docker takes 4 minutes to start on debian

Tags: docker

I observed that the docker takes 4 minutes to start each time after reboot. I have provided some details as attached. Any thoughts/tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Debian

```
-> docker -v
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
-> uname -a
Linux x 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Other logs:

```
-> systemd-analyze blame
4min 21.855s docker.service
2.863s cloud-final.service
2.021s cloud-init-local.service
1.698s cloud-init.service
1.476s cloud-config.service
…
21ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
19ms systemd-update-utmp.service
18ms docker.socket

-> sudo journalctl -u docker.service
– Logs begin at Sun 2018-05-06 20:49:58 PDT, end at Sun 2018-05-06     21:11:45 PDT. –
May 06 20:50:02 x systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine…
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23.757674968-07:00” level=debug msg=“Listener created for HTTP on fd ()”
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23.769857584-07:00” level=info msg=“libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process” pid=1328
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“starting containerd” module=containerd revision=cfd04396dc68220d1cecbe686a6cc3aa5ce3667c version=v1.0.2
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=debug msg=“changing OOM score to -500” module=containerd
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.content.v1.content”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.content.v1
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=warning msg=“failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs” error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.sn
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=warning msg=“could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin” error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshot
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.differ.v1.walking”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.differ.v1
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.gc.v1
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
May 06 20:54:23 x dockerd[654]: time=“2018-05-06T20:54:23-07:00” level=info msg=“loading plugin “io.containerd.grpc.v1.content”…” module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
```

I posted the question in docker forum, but got no luck. 
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-takes-4-minutes-to-start-on-debian/50441

====== updated #1

System info: 1G RAM, 25 GB SSD, Clean system (just installed)

```
> docker info
xiejw:x -> docker info
Containers: 8
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
Images: 15
Server Version: 18.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfd04396dc68220d1cecbe686a6cc3aa5ce3667c
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.0-6-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 996.5MiB
Name: x
ID: Y3MP:DHWK:4VES:2LEZ:RHJK:UFCB:HX2W:4CK2:XHBI:CG7B:PBT3:2LTG
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 37
 Goroutines: 45
 System Time: 2018-05-09T10:44:20.217001219-07:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: There's a lot of data we don't have besides the operating system. What's the CPU / Memory on the box? Is storage flash or traditional? If traditional what speed?

Comment: Looks like systemd says it started docker but no logs from docker for several minutes. I believe there's a dependency to create the docker.sock in there, how long does systemd show that took to run, and did the system get busy running other startup tasks in the mean time?

Comment: Also, how many containers are there, how many networks, volumes, images, and other docker objects do you have? How much disk space is used in /var/lib/docker. The output from `docker info` would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all the helps. I have updated the system information and provided the docker info in the post (see update #1).